# How to deserealize JObj Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, json

I'm using asp.net mvc4 with newtonsoft.json. I have the response from server and try to deserealize it, but have an error. Code and error in the bottom. Can anybody help me?

```
{"response":[208212605,223947262]}

var friends = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VkMutualFriends>>(response);

[JsonObject]
    public class VkMutualFriends {
        [JsonProperty("response")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }



    Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SocialAnalytics.Models.ViewModel.VkMutualFriends]' 
    because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the 
deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, 
not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
        Path 'response', line 1, position 12.
```

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657984/problem-deserialising-json-to-listt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object contains an array of integers, but you are translating to a single int. Hence the error.

Try something like

```
[JsonProperty("response")]
public int[] UserIds { get; set; }
```